# Get return value from classloader

Tags: java, return-value, classloader

I want to know how can I get this boolean return value (true/false) from the classloader?

```
public static boolean isInitialized() {
    return UnityServices.isInitialized();
}
```

The following is my code:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urlsArr);
Class loadedMyClass = cl.loadClass(className);
Constructor constructor = loadedMyClass.getConstructor();
Object myClassObject = constructor.newInstance();

// Getting the target method from the loaded class and invoke it using its name
Method method = loadedMyClass.getMethod(methodNAme);
method.invoke(myClassObject);
Log.d("Invoked", method.getName());

return //get the value;
```

Comment: What return value do you mean exactly? The return value of the method that you invoke via reflection? The `invoke(...)` method returns that, but you're ignoring it. Assign the return value of `method.invoke(...)` to a variable and return that.

Comment: The return value i mean is UnityServices.isInitialized();

Comment: What does that have to do with the second piece of code in your question? Are you calling that method via reflection?

Answer (score 0):

the value is returned by the `invoke` method, you can just do

```java
return (Boolean) method.invoke(myClassObject);
```